# Video Kit Tiktok (Response Success but not Received in Inbox)

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

I was try to Video Kit in Tiktok
[Video Kit Documentation](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/web-video-kit-with-web/)

But, sometimes the response from their API is successful and gets the share_id. But, after I checked the Tiktok application for a while, I didn't get the notification.

I use the Video Kit with Web

Has anyone experienced it too? or solve this issue?

My expectation is always get a notification when I hit the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Uploaded a video, got a successful response, and waited for days for it to get into the app. Later, I discovered, that my video was too lengthy.

According to the documentation:

1. The size of the uploaded video file must be less than or equal to 50
   MB.
2. **The duration of the video file must be at least 3 seconds and at
   most 60 seconds.**
3. The supported video file format is MP4.
4. The video resolution is at least 540p.

Hope that it helps.